# IE cannot download bmp file with unicode pathname

Tags: internet-explorer, unicode

I have a web-app that allows users to upload and download image files by pressing buttons on a web page. A user of this page is reporting that IE 7 and 8 fail to download files *when the files have Unicode pathnames*. IE prompts the user with a dialog stating: "Internet explorer cannot download (file) at (webserver).".

The problem only happens in IE. Unfortunately I have not been able to reproduce the problem using these versions on my machine.

My question is, what could cause this, and how can I prevent it from happening? I have read about problems with cache control (I currently have it set to no-cache); however, I am not using HTTP-S, and the problem only occurs with file-names containing Unicode characters.

Update: the problem appears to only happen when the user attempts to download a bmp filepath. Non-standard filepaths download successfully. Could it be that Paint is causing trouble?

The Javascript sets appends an iframe pointing at a url associated with the file.

Comment: Could you please define what 'fail to download' means? Does the download dialog not appear, or does it attempt to download + popup an error, or does it download corrupted? Also, are you using gzip on the file contents? It may seem like an irrelevant question, but I've suffered a very similar situation before.

Comment: IE prompts the user with an error dialog stating that "Internet explorer cannot download (file) from (webserver)", where <file> is a unicode filepath (an image in this case). I have updated the original question above.

Comment: As for gzip, I am not currently using compression.

Comment: @MM Can you upload some test file to this server and give us a download link to this file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the bug only occurs if you set the content-disposition header to attachment. Once I removed the header from my http response headers, the problem was resolved.

If you set the mime type to an unknown value, the bitmap will not be rendered as an image, and will be treated like an attachment.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your updated comments.

This could be:

1. Your Web Server
2. Your clients' browser extensions
3. Your filename being too long (as below, but v old articles)

I'm thinking it's most likely number 2 as you are unable to reproduce the issue (You are using real versions of the browsers, right? Not something like MultiIEs).

You can ask them to start internet explorer without extensions by running `iexplore -extoff`, and see if that makes any difference. They could also check their security settings.

I've found with IE that it could be a multitude of things causing the issue, as I mentioned before I had an 'unable to download' issue similar to this, reason being that for some reason our server was double-gzipping the contents, *only* with IE, and IE obviously didn't like that very much.

I know these articles are very out of date and I'm sure they don't apply, however they may be relevant:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816868
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/812935/en-us

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I got the user to test with extensions disabled, but that didn't resolve the problem. I'm suspicious of the security settings, although I can't quite understand why unicode paths would be affected by security. Another development: the issue only happens with bmp files...

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to url-encode the file name in the download link. The problem may be that the browser doesn't know the charset of web server's file system, so different browsers may take different assumptions about your file system's charset. Url-encoding should solve this ambiguity.